# What's the difference between Binance ERC20 and Coinbase ERC20 ...?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ether, bitcoin, address.transfer

As a newbie I made a mistake whilst transferring btc to from Binance and Coinbase. My mistake was I didn't check the receive address with Coinbase and it defaults to eth and I wanted to send btc to btc. So anyway .. I accepted the transfer of btc to eth erc20 and now the funds are lost in eth heaven .. both Binance and Coinbase say they can't help me but I don't believe that. There must be a solution to this problem where I can get my funds either restored or forwarded. Any advise ??

Comment: Binance offers withdrawals to its own blockchain, but it requires a supported wallet. Coinbase doesn't support Binance chain so if you used their address the funds are lost. Technically if Coinbase gives you their private key of their address you will have access to those funds.

Comment: thx bro ... how would I get coinbase to give me access to this private key and if I do get it how would I have access to the funds or be able to transfer back to my binance wallet ?? thx

Comment: I don't think Coinbase will ever release their private key, mainly for security reasons. If you have the private key you can import the key in a wallet that supports Binance chain and you will have access to those funds.